# changing UIButton image background in Table view cell for particular row base on som condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom table view in my app which has button in each row.
I want to change button background image when flag of that cell is i'1'(check if statement in code.).
it is successfully executing if statements.
Just the button's background image is not changing.
Here is my code

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];


if(tableView == tablePatchFilter)
{
    cell.textLabel.text=[filterPatchName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    cell.textLabel.text=[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UILabel *typeLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
    typeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    typeLabel.text = [displayItemsType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    typeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    typeLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:MyFont size:17.f];
    typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(300,2.0f,250,50);
    [cell addSubview:typeLabel];


    UILabel *typeLabel1 = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
    typeLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    typeLabel1.text = [displayItemPatch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    typeLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    typeLabel1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:MyFont size:17.f];
    typeLabel1.frame = CGRectMake(550,2.0f,250,50);
    [cell addSubview:typeLabel1];


    UILabel *typeLabel2 = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
    typeLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    typeLabel2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:MyFont size:17.f];
    typeLabel2.text = [displayItemclass objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    typeLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    typeLabel2.frame = CGRectMake(730,2.0f,250,50);
    [cell addSubview:typeLabel2];


    int selectedSegment = mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex;



    if(selectedSegment == 0)
    {





        for(int i = 0;i<[displayFlag count];i++)


        { UIButton  *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


            btn.tag=indexPath.row;

            [btn addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(takeSignature:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell addSubview:btn];


            NSMutableString *pathhh= [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[displayFlag objectAtIndex:i]];

            NSLog(@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%@",pathhh);



            if([pathhh isEqualToString:@"1"])
            {

           NSLog(@"in IFFFFFFF%@",pathhh);


                  btn.frame = CGRectMake(850,1, 50, 50);
                [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signature.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }

         else
            {   
              NSLog(@"in ELSSSSSSSSSS %@",pathhh);


                  btn.frame = CGRectMake(850,1, 50, 50);

                [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }

        }


        /*

       UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(850,1, 50, 50);
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signature.png"]
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self
                action:@selector(takeSignature:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:btn];
         */

        }










}
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:MyFont size:17.f];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: what the probelm u faced, it shows blue color , what u seen

Comment: ok the problem is.both buttons are are overlapping.. instead I want if flag for that row is one i want to change image to some other image as specified in if statement

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation every time you are creating new cell, after getting cell from "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" you have to check for cell if it nil than only create new cell using "alloc-init".

The better implementation of the particular senireo is to take a custom UITableViewCell.

The following stategie you should follow.

1. In the custom cell create the outlet for label 1, 2 and 3, than set the test in cellForRowatIndexPath.
2. Create a property of NSMutableArray in the custom cell class.
3. After getting the cell from "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" check if cell is nil than only create the buttons and add all the buttons in the NSMutableArray created in step 2.
4. take the buttons from the NSMutableArray and that apply the condition for setting the images.

Please see the below code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(tableView == tablePatchFilter)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=[filterPatchName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;

    } else {
        CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

        if (!cell) {

            cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

            int selectedSegment = mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex;

            if(selectedSegment == 0) {
                UIButton  *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

                btn.tag=indexPath.row;

                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(takeSignature:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [cell.buttonArray addObject:btn];
            }
        }

        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        cell.textLabel.text=[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        cell.label1.text = [displayItemsType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.label2.text = [displayItemPatch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.label3.text = [displayItemclass objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        for (UIButton *btn in cell.buttonArray) {
            NSMutableString *pathhh= [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[displayFlag objectAtIndex:i]];

            if([pathhh isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                btn.frame = CGRectMake(850,1, 50, 50);
                [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signature.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            } else {
                btn.frame = CGRectMake(850,1, 50, 50);
                [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }

        return cell;
    }

}
```